# How can you target a child element of an iterated object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

In this instance I simply want to target tables that have a thead tag.

I trying to concatenate or search using JavaScript or jQuery whichever is quicker.

e.g `thead = DT[i].children('thead');`

```js
function go() {
  var i = 0,
    DT = document.getElementsByClassName('DT');
  for (i; i < DT.length; ++i) {
    var x = DT[i];

    if ($(x + ' thead').length) {
      //do stuff to this table
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="DT" id="gv1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>th</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="DT" id="gv2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>thead</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to check if the nested `thead` exists.

```
if (x.querySelector("thead")) {
  //do stuff to this table
}
```

Just so you know, you'd do this to accomplish what you were trying originally:

```
if ($(x).find("thead").length) {
  //do stuff to this table
}
```

This is just to show how you can perform DOM selection from a given context.

Comment: Although `has` seems like the way to go I had some issue with getting this to work with loops your `find` solution worked a treat for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops, you can use jQuery's `:has()` selector to retrieve an element based on whether or not it contains a specified child, like this:

```js
function go() {
  $('.DT').has('thead').addClass('foo');
}

go();
```

```css
.foo { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="DT" id="gv1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>th</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="DT" id="gv2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>thead</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('.DT thead').parent().addClass('foo');`  this will also do the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, although slightly more verbose

Comment: Thanks Rory this put me on the right track. I went with `$('.DT').has('thead')` as per the jQuery recommendation. https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. To be honest I'd not seen that caveat in the docs before. I'll update the answer in case this question gets any visitors in the future.